# Redis ReadOnly You can't write against ready only slave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

I am using Redis and Sidekiq for delayed emails and an asynchronous process in a Rails 4 app. My prod environment has 2 severs. Server 1 runs Redis-master and sidekiq and Server 2 runs Redis-slave and sidekiq. I am getting an error "readonly you can't write against a read only slave". How do I configured sidekiq on server 2 to use the Redis-master on server 1? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here from Sidekiq's documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#using-sidekiqs-configure-blocks) - edit `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` and throw into it the url of the master, e.g. `redis://redis.example.com:7372`.